# how to update document using aggregation

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregate

**I have complex document I try to update using aggregate but it's only making copy when I use $out it's remove all other document I want to concate all other file to this and update........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................**

```
db.getDb().collection(coll.seat).aggregate( [
                    {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$unwind': {
                            'path': '$show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values'
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$match': {
                            'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values._id': ObjectId('62af61b72609bb5c0b664e7e')
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$addFields': {

                            'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values.seat_status': true
                        }

                    },
                    {
                         $out: 'shows' 
                    }
                 ])
```

**this is my mongo db data look like**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd1dee"),
    "totalShowByDay" : "2",
    "totalShowDays" : 4,
    "movieId" : ObjectId("62953ba3cb6ae625ec9433e6"),
    "screenId" : ObjectId("6293b9638dde2d92658d5513"),
    "createdAt" : 1654930114438,
    "showId" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ed"),
    "show_seats" : [
        {
            "showByDate" : {
                "ShowDate" : "2022-06-11",
                "shows" : [
                    {
                        "showTime" : "2022-06-11T10:00",
                        "showSeats" : [
                            [
                                {
                                    "category" : "CLASSIC",
                                    "seat_details" : [
                                        {
                                        "key" : "A",
                                        "values" : [
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ee"),
                                        "seat_number" : "1",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
,
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ef"),
                                        "seat_number" : "2",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14f0"),
                                        "seat_number" : "3",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00",,
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14ef"),
                                        "seat_number" : "2",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        },
                                        {
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("62a43ac2d7213c7233cd14f0"),
                                        "seat_number" : "3",
                                        "tag_name" : "A",
                                        "seat_status" : false,
                                        "user_id" : false,
                                        "price" : "140",
                                        "seats_category" : "CLASSIC",
                                        "show_time" : "2022-06-11T10:00"
                                        }
```

Comment: use [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) 
instead of the $out

Comment: @nimrodserok which stage i need to use merge

Comment: Instead of the `$out`

Comment: @nimrodserok getting error  `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$merge'`

Comment: You are using a mongoDB version older than 4.2...

Comment: @nimrodserok this is my mongodb vertion `"mongodb": "^4.5.0",`

Comment: @nimrodserok I use $merge but it's also work like $out it's replace everything except modified document

Comment: Please share the new query

Comment: @nimrodserok   `{
                        '$match': {
                            'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values._id': {
                                '$in': obj

                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$addFields': {

                            'show_seats.showByDate.shows.showSeats.seat_details.values.seat_status': true
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        $merge: 'seats'
                    }`

Comment: Please look at the documentation that I sent you on the first comment

Comment: Should be: `{ $merge : { into : "collection" } }`

Comment: @nimrodserok thank you for your time and effort I destructed data to simple structure now i will group in  JavaScript  and I learn more about $merge and $out thank you :)